# Flow: Excluding recordtypes

Tags: visual-workflow, workflow, email2case

I have a flow which SHOULD do the following: When the customer send in a new email for an already created case it should set the case status back to open for some rt. It works but just for ALL record types.

Now I have some rt which should be excluded from this flow. And I tried it with this approach:

[image]

Which doesn´t exclude anything. And I don´t know why. The first two conditions are clear (to me) but the rest is obvious wrong.

Comment: hello Alex, May I know, Is that `Record type Id` are correctly mapped in that condition instead of `Record type's name` or `Record type's developer name`? because seems it's like record type developer name is mapped for Ids. So could you please double check?

Comment: @MohanrajSivalingam thanks for the reply. Yes, there are ids. Myabe the label is misleading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OR doesn't work the way you (apparently) think it does. It says that if *either* value is true, then the *result* is true.

Consider this truth table:

| OR | true | false |
| --- | --- | --- |
| true | true | true |
| false | true | **false** |

If the record type *does* equal RT_Onboarding_PersoProfiler, it will *not* equal RT_Onboarding_OnboardingConsultingToDo, RT_Onboarding_Persy, etc. In other words, since *at least one* of those conditions will always be true, the result will *always* be true.

You want to use "All Conditions Are Met" for the filter criteria, rather than mixing AND and OR.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. I changed it all to And. Now nothing gets updated. Not even the ones which aren´t mention. But when I add an email from Outlook the wrong rt still gets back to open.

Comment: Upps, sorry. my bad. There was another flow which caused a problem. So it works. THANKS!